# How to groupby in different keys

Tags: python, pandas

I have `df`like following

```
A B C
a a d
a b d
a b e
b c e
b c f
```

When I try

df.groupby(A).size()

```
A
a 3
b 2
```

df.groupby(B).size()

```
B
a 1
b 2
c 2
```

my desired result is aggregated one

```
  A B
a 3 1
b 2 2
c 0 2
```

Are there any way to achieve this result ?

If someone has opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`melt` + `crosstab`

```
s = df[['A','B']].melt()
out = pd.crosstab(s['value'],s['variable'])
out
Out[18]: 
variable  A  B
value         
a         3  1
b         2  2
c         0  2
```

Or

```
df[['A','B']].apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
Out[19]: 
     A  B
a  3.0  1
b  2.0  2
c  NaN  2
```